# Show annotation in custom views

Tags: iphone, uiview

First off - I'm not using MapKit. I'm using my own controls for something entirely different. But the annotation view is something I'd like to mimmic. I've seen other applications with similar views to indicate state or actions on other controls. However, scanning through the class library I can't find a view already in the SDK. Do I have to create my own custom view that mimics this look and behavior or does the iPhone provide a standard way of showing these annotations?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I couldn't find an open source solution so I built my own. To save anyone else the trouble, the source can be found at

http://github.com/appsinyourpants/Pants-Framework/tree/master/Classes/Views/

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your own (or find an open source implementation). The annotation views are actually drawn by the map view so they don't work outside of a map.